# Do jump starts with a place for full-size car battery exist?

Tags: battery, jump-start

I have an old battery left from the old car and I need a jump starter kit. It seems all jump starters have integrated motorcycle battery inside. 
I curious whether jump starters with a place for a car battery exists?
It will be even better if they sold without the battery, so I can use my old battery (I save a lot of money on that since I'm in Siberia and to deliver jump starter here cost me twice of the price of the jump starter itself).

Comment: Something like what is mentioned in [this thread](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12440/how-do-i-add-an-auxiliary-battery-to-a-van) may be of use to you. I don't know what the availability would be to you in Siberia, though.

Comment: Keep in mind that automotive batteries are optimized for fast discharge and don't really like being drained all the way.  Most of the jump starter packs I've seen use a battery optimized for deep cycle so they can pack a bunch of electricity into a smaller space and it relies on being able to charge the fast discharge battery in the car for starting.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need a kit for anything other than convenience. All you need is a pair of [jumper cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_start_(vehicle)#Jumper_cables_.28jump_leads.29), which you can make or purchase, and you've got your jump starter right there.

I would also purchase a [trickle charger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trickle_charging) to keep my jumping battery charged when not in use. If you really want to get fancy you can make a cart or a box for it, for easy storage/use.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it! Battery box with "some modification". There is DIY video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Tf3fngKA-c